# Change index for a large 2D array using Guava

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, guava

I have a large 2D array, the dimensions are 181x361 and I want to have a custom double index (Keys) using Guava, instead of `0, 1, 2, ... 181` for rows and `0, 1, 2, ... 361` for columns, I wanted to be like

```
-90, -89 ... 88, 89, 90 for rows

-180, -179 ... 178, 179, 180 for columns
```

I saw examples here but for small arrays and can be sorted out by

```
Table<Double, Double, Double> table = HashBasedTable.create();
table.put(double1, double2, myArray[1][2]);
```

how can I do it ? , I'm new.

Comment: Do you really need a guava Table at the end of this? Or do you actually just want something which looks like an array, but with row/column indexes starting from -ve numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Table<Integer, Integer, Double> table = HashBasedTable.create();
for (int row = 0; row < 181; ++row)
  for (int col = 0; col < 361; ++col)
    table.put(row - 90, col - 180, myArray[row][col]);
```